# Create a new Copy of graph in java

Tags: java

I have two classes.

```
Class Graph {
  List<Vertex> Vertices;
}

Class Vertex {
  List<Vertex> edges;
}
```

I have to design a copy(Graph G) function which will take the Graph and return a new Graph which is deep copy of input graph object.

I tried iterating through the vertices and edges, but since it a list within a list again list within a list. It goes in infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

How can it goes into an infinite loop since the lists only contains lower level elements?

```
// To be adapted to your needs of course...
public Graph copy(Graph g) {
    Graph gg = new Graph();

    for (Vertex v : g.getVertices()) {
        Vertex vv = new Vertex();
        gg.add(vv);

        for (Edge e : v.getEdges()) {
            Edge ee = new Edge();
            vv.add(ee);
        }
    }

    return gg;
}
```